# How to access value inside the widget in the cell of a tableWidget?

Tags: c++, widget, qt5

I need to get the value inside three of my cells in my TableWidget. The thing is, everytime i add a new row, i create a new Widget. So i don't really have a reference to the widget anymore.

So i have a TableWidget, full of widget where i need their value at one point, but the only way to access it is by going to it's location

I tried to create a new widget t and s, that would host my value. But, there is an issue. It can't read the datas (most likely due to the cast).

```cpp
auto pEntity = _pEntity.lock();

    if (pEntity)
    {
        auto pTextComponent = pEntity->getComponent<TextComponent>();

        pTextComponent->ListOfDialog->clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < _TableWidget->rowCount(); i++)
        {
            QTextEdit* t = (QTextEdit*)_TableWidget->cellWidget(i, 0);
            QComboBox* s = (QComboBox*)_TableWidget->cellWidget(i, 1);
            TextVisual* ItemToPush = new TextVisual(t->toPlainText().toStdString(), s->currentText().toInt(), _colorToUse.red(), _colorToUse.green(), _colorToUse.blue());
            pTextComponent->ListOfDialog->push_back(ItemToPush);
        }
    }
    pEntity->getComponent<TextComponent>()->TextChanged();
```

For the moment i only get this: "impossible to read memory".
But what i would like (even if the solution is something else) is to be able to acces the value inside the cell of my TableWidget.
Like this ( textEdit for exemple) : t->toPlainText()->toStdString()

Comment: `QTextEdit* t = (QTextEdit*)_TableWidget->cellWidget(i, 0);` I don't like the cast. I normally use dynamic_cast<> or qobject_cast<> for this and check the resulting pointer.

Comment: @drescherjm seems like qobject_cast couldn't do it, but dynamic_cast actually worked, thank you, i'll be careful with my type of casting now ^^.